# How to get properties of parent Maven to Gradle

Tags: gradle

We have multiple projects which use maven as build automation tool these project are developed and used by multiple teams in our company. We have a parent application in which we have the generic plugin related code, we use as follows

```
<parent>
    <groupId>some.project.config</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-config</artifactId>
    <version>x.x.xx</version>
    <relativePath />
  </parent>
```

I need to use gradle for one application how can i use the properties of parent.
Is it necessary to have parent also converted to gradle to use the properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Maven Model Builder API](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuilder.html) to get the [effective model](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuildingResult.html#getEffectiveModel--)

See [MavenTransform.java](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/maven/transform/MavenTransform.java#L138) and [ModelResolverImpl.java](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform/blob/master/plugin/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/maven/transform/internal/ModelResolverImpl.java)

eg:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.apache.maven:maven-model:3.5.2'
        classpath 'org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:3.5.2'  
    }
}
configurations {
    pom 
}
dependencies {
    pom 'some.project.config:project-config:x.x.xx@pom'
}
task copyPom(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.pom.singleFile
    into "$buildDir/pom"
    rename '.*', 'pom.xml'
}
task parsePom(dependsOn: copyPom) {
    inputs.file "$buildDir/pom/pom.xml"
    doLast {
        DefaultModelBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultModelBuilderFactory();
        DefaultModelBuilder builder = factory.newInstance()
        ModelResolver modelResolver = new ModelResolverImpl(project)
        ModelBuildingRequest req = new DefaultModelBuildingRequest()
        req.pomFile = file("$buildDir/pom/pom.xml")
        req.modelResolver = modelResolver
        req.xxx = ...
        req.yyy = ...
        Model effectivePom = builder.build(req).getEffectiveModel()
        doStuff(effectivePom)
    }
}
```